# System.xml.xmlexception data at the root level is invalid. line 1 position 1, in c# WebService

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

In my webservice, I'm not able to receive the following Soap Request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sila="http://sila.coop">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ResponseEvent
            xmlns="http://sila.coop">
            <requestId>10</requestId>
            <returnValue>
                <returnCode>3</returnCode>
                <message>command 'Reset' completed successfully</message>
                <duration>PT0S</duration>
                <deviceClass>8</deviceClass>
            </returnValue>
            <responseData>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;ResponseData
                xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=&quot;http://sila.coop//schemata/ResponseType_1.2.xsd&quot;&gt;&lt;/ResponseData&gt;
            </responseData>
        </ResponseEvent>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Evertime I receive this Request, I get a http error 400 "Bad Request". The trace File looks the follwoing:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-10-10T11:58:52.8850097Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{62cc4254-c741-40d2-8453-8353edd65d1b}" />
<Execution ProcessName="EventReceiver.vshost" ProcessID="34400" ThreadID="17" />
<Channel />
<Computer>DELSB-3TWBR72</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Eine Ausnahme wird ausgelöst.</Description>
<AppDomain>EventReceiver.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Es ist ein Problem mit der vom Netzwerk empfangenen XML aufgetreten. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der inneren Ausnahme.</Message>
<StackTrace>
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.ContinueReading(Int32 bytesRead)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.DecodeBufferedMessageAsync()
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseMessageAsyncResult.BeginParse()
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.BeginParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginParseIncomingMessage(AsyncCallback asynCallback, Object state)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult..ctor(ReplyChannelAcceptor acceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, HttpPipeline pipeline, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.EnqueueContext(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(IAsyncResult listenerContextResult)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(IAsyncResult result)
bei System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
bei System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
bei System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
bei System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.IOCompleted(ListenerAsyncResult asyncResult, UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes)
bei System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
bei System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Es ist ein Problem mit der vom Netzwerk empfangenen XML aufgetreten. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der inneren Ausnahme. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Die Daten auf der obersten Ebene sind ungültig. Zeile 1, Position 1.
   bei System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   bei System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
   bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Die Daten auf der obersten Ebene sind ungültig. Zeile 1, Position 1.</Message>
<StackTrace>
bei System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
bei System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: Die Daten auf der obersten Ebene sind ungültig. Zeile 1, Position 1.
   bei System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   bei System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
   bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

I'm already tried to implement a Custom Behavior with *IDispatchMessageInspector*, but even there I'm not able to receive the request. It gets already rejected on the Web Service listener I think. What is wrong with this XML Request? How can I handle it in my Web Service? Unfortunately I'm not able to change the client code.

Comment: Perhaps a BOM slipped into your data, or it's declared as UTF-8 but is actually UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: The thing is, with the SoapUI Mock Service I can receive it with no Problems.